# Set server ACL folders 755 and files 644 permissions

Tags: linux, ubuntu, web-server, access-control-list

In /var/www, I want all folders (recursively) to have the permissions of 755. I want all files to have the permission of 644. I want all new files and folders to take on these permissions as well.

I've been looking at many examples but I feel like I'm never going to figure this out. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**For Files** :

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

**For Folders** :

```
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

These will change all the file permissions to 644 and set the permissions to 755 for folders.

Answer (score 0):

```
chmod -R a-rwX /dir
chmod -R u=rwX,g=rX,o=rX /dir
```

Comment: This answer should include some more information about what is going on.